# Can the new HatchShading and StippleShading plotstyles be used without color?

Tags: plotting

I wanted (PlotStyles) HatchShading or StippleShading for figures that will be printed in black and white, but these options end up color by default.  I tried combining with a GrayTones ColorFunction, like so:

```
scap = {Sin[#1] Cos[#2], Sin[#1] Sin[#2], Cos[#1]} & ;
{ParametricPlot3D[ {Sin[t]^2 scap[t, p]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}
  , Lighting -> "Accent"
  , ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"
  ],
 ParametricPlot3D[ {Sin[t]^2 scap[t, p]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}
  , Lighting -> "Accent"
  , ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"
  , PlotStyle -> HatchShading[0.7, Black]
  ],
 ParametricPlot3D[ {Sin[t]^2 scap[t, p]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}
  , Lighting -> "Accent"
  , ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"
  , PlotStyle -> StippleShading[]
  ]}
```

but the GrayTones ColorFunction seems to be ignored when using these PlotStyles.

[image: some plots]

Is there a way to avoid the use of a color background in the plot image when using HatchShading or StippleShading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the option `PlotTheme -> None` to get

[image]